# pd.DataFrame question: changing a value in a cell based on a list of conditions

Tags: pandas

I have the following data on transport mode and time. I'd like to swap values in the 'mode' and 'time' columns, when the value is not a specific value from a list. For example, in the image shown (click link below), I want to move the cells that have "10 minutes" into the "time" column, and swap those values in the "time" column to the "mode" column.

[my table](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ct8muige728vgef/Screenshot%202019-04-06%2013.11.44.png?dl=0)

I've tried a number of approaches, including the np.where function, but I'm unable to figure it out. So I've settled on a for loop. See below.

```
newdtf = pd.DataFrame()

for value in transport2['mode'].unique():

    mylist = ["Dala-dala", "Boda-boda", "Walk", "Private vehicle", 
              "Bicycle", "BRT", "Bajaj", "Traffic", "Uber"]
    if value in mylist:
    continue
    else:
        tempdtf=pd.DataFrame({'hhid': transport2.loc[transport2.time == mode, 'hhid'], 
                              'mode': transport2.loc[transport2.time == mode, 'mode'], 
                             'time': mode})

    #Join
    newdtf = newdtf.append(tempdtf)
```

However, the newdtf is not rendering the results I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I recreate your dataframe. It would bee helpful in future questions if you did this step when asking questions in stackoverflow.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'mode':['Dala-dala','Dala-dala','Dala-dala','Dala-dala','Dala-dala', '10 minutes', '10 minutes', 'Dala-dala', 'Private vehicle', 'Private vehicle'], 
              'time':['30 minutes', '20 minutes', '20 minutes', '2 hours 30 minutes', '10 minutes', 'Walk', 'Walk', '60 minutes', '3 hours', '2 hours 30 minutes']})

mylist = ["Dala-dala", "Boda-boda", "Walk", "Private vehicle", 
              "Bicycle", "BRT", "Bajaj", "Traffic", "Uber"]
```

Next we create a new temporary column to hold the filtered 'mode' values, filtered on your list.

```
df['mode_temp']= df[~df['mode'].isin(mylist)]['mode']
```

Next we filter the dataframe for values in mode_temp and then make 'mode' equal to 'time'.

```
df['mode'][df['mode_temp'].notnull()]= df['time']
```

Repeat and make 'time' equal to 'mode'.

```
df['time'][df['mode_temp'].notnull()]= df['mode_temp']
```

Drop the temporary column.

```
df = df[['mode', 'time']]

df

             mode                time
0        Dala-dala          30 minutes
1        Dala-dala          20 minutes
2        Dala-dala          20 minutes
3        Dala-dala  2 hours 30 minutes
4        Dala-dala          10 minutes
5             Walk          10 minutes
6             Walk          10 minutes
7        Dala-dala          60 minutes
8  Private vehicle             3 hours
9  Private vehicle  2 hours 30 minutes
```

Altogether the code looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'mode':['Dala-dala','Dala-dala','Dala-dala','Dala-dala','Dala-dala', '10 minutes', '10 minutes', 'Dala-dala', 'Private vehicle', 'Private vehicle'], 
              'time':['30 minutes', '20 minutes', '20 minutes', '2 hours 30 minutes', '10 minutes', 'Walk', 'Walk', '60 minutes', '3 hours', '2 hours 30 minutes']})

mylist = ["Dala-dala", "Boda-boda", "Walk", "Private vehicle", 
              "Bicycle", "BRT", "Bajaj", "Traffic", "Uber"]

df['mode_temp']= df[~df['mode'].isin(mylist)]['mode']

df['mode'][df['mode_temp'].notnull()]= df['time']

df['time'][df['mode_temp'].notnull()]= df['mode_temp']

df = df[['mode', 'time']]
```

Comment: Wow thanks so much! Would have never figured this out! Sure, next time, I'll make sure to add the data frame instead of attaching a picture. You have saved me a lot of time away from Excel!